# Silex render controller inside twig error

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm trying to render a controller inside a twig template with this:

```
{{ render(url('contact_form')) }}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to add function "asset" as extensions have already been initialized.")

I have a twig function called asset, like this:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    // add custom globals, filters, tags, ...

    $twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) use ($app) {
        return $app['request_stack']->getMasterRequest()->getBasepath().'/'.$asset;
    }));

    return $twig;
});
```

It seems that silex is trying to add, again, the asset function in the render().

I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to ignore the error by wrapping it with a try/catch block for it to work. It's a dirty solution but worked.

```
try {
    $twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) use ($app) {
        return $app['request_stack']->getMasterRequest()->getBasepath().'/'.$asset;
    }));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is already a function for twig called asset you need to call your asset custom function to something else as the error says, it has already been initialized.

Comment: There isn't a native asset function. If I open a url in a browser it works perfectly but If I try to render a controller inside a twig template silex try to define again the asset function,

Comment: symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset i use te asset function quiet enough so i still think it exist, i am not sure if you are overiding it now but weird things might happen, just change the name of your custom function

Comment: This is for symfony, I'm using silex.